# Installed App with Brew Cask Over Existing Install, Did it Remove the Old App Files?

Tags: install, homebrew, macos, symlink

I upgraded to the latest OpenOffice (from 3.4.1 to 4.1.1) with brew-cask without realizing OpenOffice 4 was already installed:

```
$ brew cask install openoffice
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/openofficeorg.mirror/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_MacOS_x86-64_install_en-US.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Symlinking App 'OpenOffice.app' to '/Users/shwaydogg/Applications/OpenOffice.app'
  openoffice staged at '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/openoffice/4.1.1' (3180 files, 385M)
```

I'm worried that the old install with ~400MB is still there just not linked.  Or does brew-cask writing the the symlink over the old app effectively delete the files?  / Perhaps BrewCask was smart enough to take this into account?

How could I check?

---

update:  did as @njbook suggested in comments:

```
$ brew-cask cleanup
==> Removing dead symlinks
Nothing to do
==> Removing cached downloads
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openoffice-4.1.1.dmg
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Casks/openoffice-4.1.1.dmg
```

There's no mention of the an old install being removed.

Another way to phrase my question perhaps more directly is in a unix system if a directory is replaced with a symlink pointing elsewhere are the files within the directory still taking up space on disk and if so how can they be found?

Comment: "Perhaps BrewCask was smart enough to take this into account?” Perhaps. If not, running `brew cleanup` usually does the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cask does not clean up old versions by default. It stages the installs in `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/$APPNAME` and then symlinks them in to `~/Applications` or `/Applications` depending on the brew recipe. And then it leaves the old versions around until you run `brew cleanup`.

You can see old installs of OpenOffice under `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/openoffice`. You can safely delete the old installs from there, though `brew cleanup` is supposed to do this for you.

If you had previously installed OpenOffice using their DMG installer and *not* Homebrew Cask, it was most likely installed in `/Applications` and not `~/Applications`. Cask won't install over top of an *existing* installation that *wasn't* previously Cask-installed itself. So check `/Applications` and make sure you remove the old version from there if hadn't installed it via Cask. If you had installed it via Cask all you need to do is delete it from `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/openoffice` as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Ian!  A `rm -rf /Applications/OpenOffice.app` later and good to go!.  The obvious next question is how to install "globally" and answer (even if clunky) looks to be:  `brew cask install --appdir="/Applications" openoffice`.   -- source: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/2261

Comment: @Shwaydogg yes, that's how you install globally instead of just for you.

Comment: Also found this for permanently installing to `/Applications`: Add the following to .bashrc `export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications"`  -- source comment section here:http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/perfect-configurations-with-homebrew-and-cask--cms-20768